# If a function $u \in L^p$ in a Lebesgue space has a weak derivative, in what Lebesgue space is the weak derivative?

Tags: lp-spaces, sobolev-spaces, weak-derivatives

Suppose that a function $u : \mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is locally integrable.

Suppose furthermore that it has a weak derivative $w : \mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb R^n$, that is, the $\nabla u := w$ has locally integrable components and we have

$$ -\int_{\mathbb R^n} w \phi dx = \int_{\mathbb R^n} u\partial_i \phi dx $$

for all compactly supported smooth functions $\phi : \mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb R$.

If $u$ is in the Lebesgue space $L^p$ for some $1 \leq p \leq \infty$, what do we know about the possible Lebesgue space of its weak derivative $w$?

Does $u \in L^p$ and weakly differentiable automatically imply that $\nabla u \in L^q$ for some $q \in [1,\infty]$? Or can it happen (for some $p$) that $\nabla u$ is merely locally integrable?

Comment: In 1-d you can use the fundamental theorem of calculus to construct examples of $u\in C_c(\mathbb{R})$ (i.e. continuous with compact support), and weakly differentiable but with only locally integrable derivative.

Comment: $u$ could be defined by $u(x) = \sin( v(x))$ with $v$ a crazy function.